# Ruby Sinatra Datamapper/database confusion

Tags: ruby, database, ruby-datamapper

I'm confused as to how database relationship works.

Say I have a Border Crossing('crossing'), which has two 
Directions('north', 'south'), each of which direction has 2 types of lanes ('normal','fast'), each of which lane has 2 metrics (=data) ('delay','queue_length').

In reality there are several crossings, with more lane types and more metrics.

How the heck should I store that in a database? I've used databases before, but never did table joins or one-to-many or anything like that.

I came across Datamapper and since I'm learning how to us Sinatra I thought I'd give it a go.
In the tutorial (http://datamapper.org/getting-started.html), the "one-to-many" part just screamed "this is what you need", so I started fiddling around.

```
    require 'data_mapper'

    DataMapper.setup(:default, ENV['DATABASE_URL'] || "sqlite3://#{Dir.pwd}/development.db")

      class Crossing
      include DataMapper::Resource

      property :id, Serial
      property :name, String,:unique=>true
      has n, :directions
    end

    class Direction
      include DataMapper::Resource

      property :id, Serial
      property :direction, String,:unique=>true
      belongs_to :crossing
      has n, :lanes
    end

    class Lane
      include DataMapper::Resource

      property :id, Serial
      property :lane, String
      belongs_to :direction
      has n, :datas
    end

    class Data
      include DataMapper::Resource

      property :id, Serial
      property :name, String,:unique=>true
      property :value, String
      belongs_to :lane
    end

    DataMapper.finalize.auto_migrate!
```

I just thought this looked so elegantly put: "crossing has n directions, directions has n lanes, etc"

Then:

```
    Crossing.create(:name => "crossing")

    Direction.create(:direction => "north")
    Direction.create(:direction => "south")

    Lane.create(:lane => 'normal')
    Lane.create(:lane => 'fast')

    Data.create(:data => 'delay')
    Data.create(:data => 'queue_length')

    // now how do I retrieve find the data of a lane of a direction of a crossing?
```

Now, what I will input and retrieve all the time is the Data part. Does this whole thing make sense or I'm just not understanding what table associations are for? I know I could just have a gigantic object instead of this but I'm pretty sure that's a weird way of doing things.

```
    @crossing = {
      'crossing name' => {

        :directions => {

          :north => {

            :normal => {

              :delay => '10 min',

              :queue => '100 m'
            },

            :fast => {

              :delay => '1 min',

              :queue => '10 m'
            }
          },

          etc etc etc

    }
```

and then access the data like @crossing[:north][:normal][:delay]....but I kinda feel like a database would be better?

Am I making any sense in any way? Anybody got some pointers for a young grasshoper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would rather go with this structure:

- `Data` belongs to `Crossing`, `Direction` and `Lane`; it has properties for `delay` and `queue`
- `Direction` has many `Data`, and has exactly two rows
- `Lane` has many `Data`, and has exactly two rows
- `Crossing` has many `Data`, and has many rows

The reason is, you don't want to repeat the strings `"north"`, `"south"` etc in your database.

Then, first seed the database with constant tables:

```
Direction.create(direction: 'north')
Direction.create(direction: 'south')

Lane.create(lane: 'normal')
Lane.create(lane: 'fast')
```

Then you can make your crossings:

```
cool_crossing = Crossing.create(name: 'My Cool Crossing')
not_cool_crossing = Lane.create(name: 'My Not So Cool Crossing')
```

and add data points:

```
north = Direction.first(name: "north")
normal = Lane.first(name: "normal")

Data.create(
  crossing: cool_crossing,
  lane: normal,
  direction: north,
  delay: 10,
  queue: 1
)
```

and retrieve data by:

```
all_data_for_cool_crossing = Data.all(
  crossing: cool_crossing
)
```

or

```
data_for_cool_crossing_normal_north = Data.first(
  crossing: cool_crossing,
  lane: normal,
  direction: north
)
```

Comment: This is way cool! There were just a few more hoops (i can't use Data because "There is a built-in type named Data") Thank you so much!

Comment: Yeah, sorry, didn't test at all.